# Why is font smoothing disabled on academia?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

With my current setup: Google Chrome, OS X Yosemite, a 27 inches 2560x1440 monitor, somehow the font used on academia -- and probably other -- is not using sub pixel font smoothing. It is not legible. Is there a justification for this ? I don't feel like diving into CSS and custom style right now, so if there is a quick fix,  I would like to know it.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is that this is not an Academia issue, but a browser or Yosemite issue. If I examine the same page in Safari or Google, I get a very different appearance than when I try to view the site in Firefox (for instance). I personally find the text in Firefox easier to read, as it is "heavier" and stands out better against the background.

Comment: Confirmed. Safari and Chrome on OS X won't smooth fonts. However Linux Chrome and OS X Firefox do smooth fonts.